# Column result unexpectedly returning nothing

Tags: sparql

Have a SPARQL query that returns nothing for `Airport_Name` when I believe it should.

```
 PREFIX nas: <https://data.nasa.gov/ontologies/atmonto/NAS#>
 PREFIX gen: <https://data.nasa.gov/ontologies/atmonto/general#>


SELECT *
WHERE{
{
{SELECT ?Airport_Name{
    ?Airport rdf:type nas:Airport ;
    nas:airportName ?Airport_Name .
    }
}

}UNION{
    ?Location rdf:type gen:PointLocation;
    gen:longitude ?X ;
    gen:latitude ?Y .

}


?Location rdf:type gen:PointLocation;
gen:longitude ?X ;
gen:latitude ?Y .
FILTER (?X > -80 && ?X < -64 && ?Y > 18 && ?Y < 32)
```

}

Expected result should return `Location`, `X`, `Y`, and `Airport_Name`

[image: Example result]

When I try to return `Airport_Name` at the bottom, the `Location` columns then appear blank, so im not sure what has been done wrongly. If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: would e helpful to mention the goal of the query. so, why the subquery? and why the `UNION`? And the `?Airport` and `?Location` are different, so what would be the relation here? In the end, it returns the crossproduct.

Comment: And then, which dataset or SPARQL endpoint?

Comment: Ok, so it's the NASA dataset. But again, did you check the data model? I mean, you have to find the "path" between the `Airport` instance and the `PointLocation` instance. As far as I can see, there is no direct relation so I still don't understand the purpose of your current query.

Comment: Nevertheless, `gen:longitude` and `gen:latitude` are both `xsd:float` values. For example, you have `gen:latitude "3.455E1"^^xsd:float` in the dataset. That has to be taken into account in your filter. Something like `FILTER (?X > "-80"^^xsd:float ...`

Comment: The goal of the query it to return the name and coordinates of airports within a certain set of coordinates. I assumed you needed a UNION as I was returning results from both NAS and General

Comment: No, you don't need a UNION. But you have to figure out the relation in the dataset between the airport and the location data. And in the query the variables have to be shared or then "connected" via triple patterns. Something like `?airport rdf:type :Airport . ?airport :hasLocation ?location . ?location rdf:type :Location . ?location geo:lat ?lat . FILTER(?lat < ...` - note, this was just a fictional data and doesn't reflect your dataset, I hope you get the idea. So your task now is to dig into the dataset and find a "path" from airport to geo data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has several issues, the correct query would be something like below.

#### Query

```sql
SELECT  *
WHERE
  { ?airport  rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf*  nas:Airport ;
              nas:airportName      ?Airport_Name ;
              nas:airportLocation  ?location .
    ?location  gen:longitude       ?X ;
               gen:latitude        ?Y
    FILTER ( ?X > "-80"^^xsd:float && ?X < "-64"^^xsd:float && ?Y > "18"^^xsd:float && ?Y < "32"^^xsd:float )
  }
```

#### Result (sample with `LIMIT 10`)

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| airport         | Airport_Name                | location            | X                       | Y                      |
==========================================================================================================================
| nas:MYEMairport | "Governors Harbour"         | nas:MYEMcoordinates | "-76.330178"^^xsd:float | "25.283586"^^xsd:float |
| nas:MDPCairport | "Punta Cana Intl"           | nas:MDPCcoordinates | "-68.366186"^^xsd:float | "18.570781"^^xsd:float |
| nas:MUGTairport | "Mariana Grajales"          | nas:MUGTcoordinates | "-75.158333"^^xsd:float | "20.085278"^^xsd:float |
| nas:MDSTairport | "Cibao Intl"                | nas:MDSTcoordinates | "-70.604689"^^xsd:float | "19.406092"^^xsd:float |
| nas:MYLSairport | "Stella Maris"              | nas:MYLScoordinates | "-75.268778"^^xsd:float | "23.583047"^^xsd:float |
| nas:MBNCairport | "North Caicos"              | nas:MBNCcoordinates | "-71.939658"^^xsd:float | "21.917486"^^xsd:float |
| nas:MUMOairport | "Orestes Acosta"            | nas:MUMOcoordinates | "-74.922222"^^xsd:float | "20.653889"^^xsd:float |
| nas:MYRPairport | "New Port Nelson"           | nas:MYRPcoordinates | "-74.836186"^^xsd:float | "23.684378"^^xsd:float |
| nas:MYEGairport | "George Town"               | nas:MYEGcoordinates | "-75.781670"^^xsd:float | "23.466667"^^xsd:float |
| nas:MUBYairport | "Carlos Manuel De Cespedes" | nas:MUBYcoordinates | "-76.621389"^^xsd:float | "20.396389"^^xsd:float |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note, the query uses the property path `rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf*` which only works if you've also loaded the ontology (`NAS.ttl`). The property path is necessary because the instance data (`airportInst.ttl`) uses subclasses of `nas:Airport` like `nas:InternationAirport` or `nas:CanadianAirport`.